# Why am I getting "Possible null reference assignment" after upgrading to net7.0 in my Azure function?

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception, .net-7.0

I upgraded my Azure function from net6.0 to 7 and now I'm getting lots of warnings like this below that are pestering me about possible null references.

I know why there's a warning, but why now only after upgrading to net7.0?

**QUESTION** - Does C# expect me to correct this someway or is there something I can do to suppress these warnings?

I know I can do a check like

```
if (somevalue is not null)
```

but then I have conditional statements all over the place, which I don't want/need!

Here Email is nullable.

[image]

Another example from the same Azure function

[image]

Here above Email is from Identity and I always collect this data when a user registers, so it will never be null but I can't change it's nullability.

So I could do this to fix it
[image]

But is this what they now want?

Comment: You can suppress the warnings based on the warning identifier, but of course best thing would be to make sure the checks are there. The defaults and checks change when new versions come out so that’s why it’s complaining now. In the latter screenshot you don’t even need any separate ifs, you can use `int.TryParse()` for example instead of crashing.

Comment: Actually I was able to fix the later example by using "jsonObject["value"]?.ToString(), but there are lots of other values that I don't want or need to check on, ex. IdentityUser -> Email like in the first example. I don't need to check this 500 times as this value is always populated when a user created a login, even though it's a nullable type in the SQL tables

Comment: I would guess that the 'why' is that support for the new null reference types syntax is an ongoing process. So overtime support is going to be added to existing codebases, and when upgrading you are going to run into stuff that didn't use null reference types and now do, and now cause warnings to appear.

Comment: @user1186050 Btw, the new null reference types is completely optional. You can opt out of it in the project settings file. The whole null reference types is just compiler sugar - it tries to guess where it thinks you might hit a null reference exception because you didn't check if something was null first, and then warns you. However, it doesn't actually prevent nulls from entering your code paths.

Comment: @B.O.B Hi bob, I just updated my post to reflect the most annoying warning, related to Identity and Emails and Usernames on the Identity class. Maybe you can advise on this?

Comment: Oh I see where it's coming from, it's coming from "<Nullable>enable</Nullable>" in my csproj file. This is new to me...

Comment: @user1186050 Yes. Again, all that is doing is the compiler attempting to detect something might be null when it shouldn't and give you a compiler warning. You can either turn off this feature, or you have to refactor your entire code base to get rid of the warnings. You could also just turn it off in specific source files. PS: the '?' operator you used to suppress the warning is actually syntax sugar. Visual Studio is literally rewriting your code under the hood to do the null check for you.

Comment: @user1186050 Also more syntax sugar: the new '!' operator. This tells compiler to ignore that something might be null and just continue on. IE, `creditCard!.StripeCustomer!.User!.Email!` would suppress the warning on that line. Course I would work backwards from that route. IE, I would try `creditCard.StripeCustomer.User.Email!` first and see if that suppresses the entire warning, and then just add '!' further up the chain as needed.

Comment: As to my comment about it not preventing nulls, let's say `SomeProperty` on `SomeClass` should never be set to null and would cause your app to crash. The new <Nullable>enable</Nullable> might detect that SomeProperty shouldn't be assigned null, but you could literally do this: `someClass.SomeProperty = null!;` and the compiler would like 'everything is fine!' and compile - but your app would crash at that line.

Comment: @B.O.B. Is this new "!" operator like "?", just syntactical sugar! I mean ther are plenty of properties where I know there won't be a null and can use "?" or "!", but ...

Comment: And what would the difference be between these: jsonObject["PayoutId"]!.ToString() and jsonObject["PayoutId"]?.ToString() as they both suppress the warning

Comment: @user1186050 The '!' is not syntax sugar because it's not generating new source code for you. It's just telling the compiler to ignore what it thinks might be null. So it's more compiler sugar (IMO). It's basically you telling the compile "Yes I know you think it can be null, but I know for a fact it isn't null so be quiet." Of course if you are wrong then you get a null reference exception at runtime.

Comment: So to answer your question, if you know something cannot possibly be null, then I would guess if you were to benchmark it, the ! operator would be slightly more performant cause no extra code is actually added / compiled - but the ? will replace `x?.DoSomething();` with `if (x is not null) { x.DoSomething(); }`. Of course compilers are tricky business and the compiler might realize that x is never null and skip the `if` or the JIT runtime might also optimize it away. So who knows?

Comment: Are you good with exception handling in C# apps? I ask because I want to push to production soon and I'm not that stong with exception handling. Meaning, I have a exception handling class (middleware) in the app I found/used from someone else, but not sure what to do now or how to handle notifications. I have the logger working and sending me emails when there is an exception, but it doesn't actually show what the exception is! It's message is pretty obscure. It doesn't show any line number or exception type.

Comment: One issue I would say I have is if I get some exception bombing my app after querying from the db with linq, my exception middle doesn't get hit/triggered for some reason. The app just kinda bombs out!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253937/discussion-between-b-o-b-and-user1186050).